# Video won't display in WPF project using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get video to display in my WPF app, written in C# using Xamarin.Forms. It compiles, but the video doesn't display.

I apologize for my long-winded question. I'm trying to provide as much background and detail as I can.

I don't have a lot of coding experience, but I've been working on a personal project for a few years.  I originally wrote a Windows app in C# using .NET Framework.  I want to make it available on MacOS and Windows, so I started rewriting it using C#, Xamarin, and .NET 5.0.

Originally, I was asking how to get it working in my app.  After a suggestion from ToolMakerSteve, I went back to the MediaElementDemos example, got it working on the Android emulator, then added a WPF project.

While I was trying to learn how to display video, I loaded a mediaelement example [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/MediaElementDemos) and was able to display video in an Android emulator. I then added in a WPF project according to instructions found [here](https://dev.to/krdmllr/setting-up-a-xamarin-forms-wpf-backend-on-net-core-109l).

I set the WPF project as the startup project. When I tried to run it, it errored out with

```
 Xamarin.Essentials.NotImplementedInReferenceAssemblyException: 'This
 functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.     You 
should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to 
reference the platform-specific implementation.'
```

pointing to

```
await FileAccess.CopyVideoIfNotExists("XamarinForms101UsingEmbeddedImages.mp4");
```

in the App.Xaml.cs file:

```
using MediaElementDemos.Helpers;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MediaElementDemos
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override async void OnStart()
        {
            await FileAccess.CopyVideoIfNotExists("XamarinForms101UsingEmbeddedImages.mp4");
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out that line

```
await FileAccess.CopyVideoIfNotExists("XamarinForms101UsingEmbeddedImages.mp4");
```

then the application runs, but no video is displayed, regardless of which menu option I choose.

I'm not sure where to look to solve this problem. I've been stuck on this for a few weeks and have begun going in circles with my google searches.

I am willing to learn and do research, and not just asking for a handout.  I just don't know where else to look for answers.  Thank you in advance for any help or guidance you can provide.

Comment: I don't have any idea why it doesn't work, but I highly recommend including either Android or iOS project also. Even though you don't need it. REASON: Those have been around much longer, hence have fewer bugs. If it works on one of those, then you know the issue is specific to WPF implementation. Hence, you could file a bug report vs X-Forms WPF.

Comment: Thank you, ToolmakerSteve. I loaded the sample project again and was finally able to get it working on the Android emulator.  I added a WPF project, and getting an error. I edited my question to reflect that narrower scope of an error received from a working example with a WPF project added.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but note "You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.'  Is there a WPF-specific Nuget for any packages that you use? If so, add to the WPF project. If not, I'm not sure how to fix.

Comment: There is a WPF-specific Nuget package for xamarin.forms (xamarin.forms.platform.wpf) that I already have added to the WPF project.  
I also have the following nuget packages added: 
xamarin.communitytoolkit 1.1.0 - all projects
xamarin.forms 5.0.0.2012 - all projects
xamarin.essentials 1.6.1- all projects
NETStandard.Library 2.0.3 - all projects

Comment: Since the error message is from Xamarin.Essentials, and it doesn't make it clear exactly what support is missing (from the cross-platform nuget), please add a comment on [Xamarin.Essentials - Additional Platform Support](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/662). There, add a link back to this topic. Also summarize the situation in that comment. Most importanty, that it does work in Android. And ask "Is there a workaround to display a video element under WPF?"